# restarting mysql

Tags: mysql

I try to restart mysql server on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
viggy@ubuntu:/$ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql restart

viggy@ubuntu:/$ service mysql restart
stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.83" (uid=1000 pid=4395 comm="stop mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

I'm not sure what that message is saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be root or use

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

in order to send the restart command as root.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`mysql` is the client. You probably want `service mysqld restart`</strike>. And unless you're running as root, you'll probably want to add `sudo` to the command as well.

Comment: Turns out Ubuntu's brain-dead design decisions are continuing. Why on earth they'd make the service named `mysql` that starts the `mysqld` process is beyond me.

Comment: Because Shuttleworth...